# Interpreting field type to activate checkboxes in c#

Tags: c#

I have some trouble building a good algorithm. Here is my criteria: I am reading a field in an xml file as a string and trying to interpret it in order to activate some gui component. More specifically, the field i read in as a string is a "Allowed Characters" field and the gui components are checkboxes that activate based on the contents of the field. For example, in the xml i have the tag

```
<Allowed Field>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</Allowed Fields>.
```

When i read in this field as a string, the program should know that the field content type is ALPHA and check the checkbox named alpha. Likewise if the field had alphanumeric contents or any special characters. I have three checkboxes that the algorithm should interpret: Alpha, alphanumeric and special characters. How can i build the algorithm that interprets the meaning of the string i read from the xml to mean the mentioned field types?

Thanks

Comment: i have tried just a string.contains. SO for example, one if statement takes into account alpha by checking it has an A and doesnt contain 0 but this way is not at all efficient

Comment: Yeah, this is not. But you should've posted some code so it's clear you made some effort. Please see my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static FieldKind AnalyzeKind (string s)
{
    bool hasNumbers, hasSpecial;

    foreach (char c in s) {
        if (Char.IsNumber (c))
            hasNumbers = true;

        else if (!Char.IsLetter (c))
            return FieldKind.AlphaNumericWithSpecialCharacters;
    }

    return (hasNumbers) ? FieldKind.AlphaNumeric : FieldKind.Alpha;
}
```

The rest depends on what you define as special characters (e.g. what is whitespace? punctuation?).
[`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) methods for your reference.

Comment: Your algorithm will not break after the first if statement if the character is a number, it will return true that it is NOT a letter in the second if statement, and then you will get to the return with SpecialCharacters. You need a break in your first if or make the second if an else if.

Comment: @Gweebz: thanks for spotting this. My mistake. I don't want to `break` because it may still be a special character and the OP didn't quite define this “specialness” so I can't test it right away.

Comment: special characters are basically anything else on the keyboard apart from a-z and 0-9. I think your method will work for this specialness right?

Comment: I guess so. Give it a try and you'll know.

Comment: there is no case for just numeric in the method

Comment: You didn't ask for one, did you!

Comment: @Joe: well, you've got the sample so you feel free to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

This is another possible application of Regex.

```
static Regex isAlpha = new Regex("^[A-Za-z]+$");
static Regex isAlphaNumeric = new Regex("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$");

static FieldKind AnalyzeKind (string s)
{
    if(isAlpha.IsMatch(s)) return FieldKind.Alpha;
    if(isAlphaNumeric.IsMatch(s)) return FieldKind.AlphaNumeric;
    return FieldKind.AlphaNumericWithSpecialCharacters;
}
```

If you are going to be calling AnalyseKind a lot in the program, you could speed it up a tad by setting RegexOptions.Compiled in the Regex constructors.

Comment: Yeah, probably a cleaner solution than mine.

Comment: This would definitely be a suitable use of Regex's. Nice method!

Comment: Depending on whether "" counts as Alpha, AlphaNumeric, or what, you may want to change one or more of the "+" characters in the regexes to "*" (i.e. match 0 or more, instead of match 1 or more).